# Perron-Frobenius Theorem poof by Brouwer fixed point

Tags: fixed-point-theorems, spectral-radius, nonnegative-matrices

Could you suggest me a book where I can find a proof of Perron-Frobenius theorem (especially for nonnegative matrices) based on a Brouwer fixed point theorem?

Comment: You shouldn't need to refer a book. Try applying Brouwer's fixed point theorem on the portion of the unit ball in the positive quadrant/octant (i.e. all coordinates $> 0$) and consider the map $v \mapsto Av/||Av||$. What does a fixed point here imply?

Comment: The problem is that I need this book to my graduate work.

Comment: @OsamaGhani Don't we need a compact set for Brouwer?

Comment: I don't want to prove by this way. I have already proved it by using graphs. Now I'm looking for some informations about different ways and different proofs and note where I can find it.

Comment: @saulspatz sorry I meant all coordinates $\geq 0$.

Answer (score 1):

Since the OP is, according to one of her comments, looking for different proofs of the Perron-Frobenius theorem, it might be wortwhile to point out the following survey paper:

C. R. MacCluer: *The many proofs and applications of Perron’s theorem*, SIAM Rev. 42, No. 3, 487-498, 2000 ([link to zbMATH](https://zbmath.org/?q=an%3A0959.15022)).

While the paper deals mainly with matrices with positive entries, it contains a large list of references, and surely many of them also deal with non-negative matrices. For instance, a long list of references to proofs by means of Brouwer's fixed point theorem can be found on page 494.